# LinQ ExecuteStoreQuery calling stored procedure returning null values

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to use linq to call a stored procedure. Here is my code:

```
List<AllRowsMyDTO> list = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<AllRowsMyDTO>("exec GetAllRows {0}", ClassID).AsQueryable().ToList();

public class AllRowsMyDTO
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentLevel { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string StudentPreRequisites { get; set; }
    public bool IsGraded { get; set; }
}
```

The GetAllRows stored procedure takes in a single integer parameter and runs a select statement fetching all records matching that ClassID. Now the list contains as many objects of type AllRowsMyDTO as there are rows returned by the stored procedure. But all the properties are null except for the boolean property. Any idea what is going on here?

Also, is this the best way to call a stored procedure using LinQ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do the column names match the property names exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't specify the key in the mapping, and EF can't figure out what it should be. EF requires a key of some form for the results (can be a compound key, if need be).

Comment: how do I specify the key when mapping?

Comment: One way is to use an entity type with a defined key. The `[Key]` attribute on the column or columns might work; I haven't tested.

Comment: Hmmm, I can capture results of a sproc in a POCO without any data annotations. But the database field and property names should match exactly (well, case insensitive).